# Indexing Cell Reference

Tags: excel-formula

I need a way to reference Cell A1 in Cells C1:C16, then B2 in Cells C17:C32, and so on for a few thousand rows, so manual data entry would be very tedious.  I am able to get the proper row to reference using the fomula:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(1+(ROW()-1)/16,0)
```

This formula produces the number 1 for rows 1:16, the number 2 for rows 17:32 etc.

But once I have that row number, I am not sure how I can reference the contents of column A in the row determined by a formula.

I was trying something like:

```
=$A(ROUNDDOWN(1+(ROW()-1)/16,0))
```

so that once the formula is evaluated, it becomes $A# where # is the intended row number, but obviously that is not syntax that excel recognizes.  Any ideas on how to go about getting the correct cell references would be appreciated.

Comment: Feed the calculated row into `=INDEX($A:$A, row, 1)`

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The same answered through Comment by @chris neilsen and the same accepted by  @User247365

Here your go for an answer!

**Feed the calculated row into**

```
=INDEX($A:$A, row, 1)
```